How to get seperate Scrollbars X and Y in different divs with CSS Overflow
I'm trying to get a y-axis scrollbar inside a container to scroll 2 seperate divs, while having x-scrollbars on both of those divs individually. But it either doesn't show up at all, or destroys any dimensions of my divs when I add overflow properties...
I marked the ones I need with "overflow: scroll". Hopes this helps in the very colorful example^^
Sorry for that. It helps me learn the effects of the different CSS Properties on the individual divs.
Furthermore the page doesn't scale as expected. I tried to implement the fiddle example from another stack post: https://jsfiddle.net/2kh20Lsz/ to have static header and footer, but that didn't really work in combination with the scrollbars I need in the middle.
Hope somebody knows how to get those things scrolling.
Full example: https://jsfiddle.net/MBittel/w8cvumqh/



html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
  
div {
  margin: 5px;
}

p {
  margin: 5px;
  background: green;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

#main-header, #footer {
  background: silver;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#categoryViewContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
  background: orange;
}

#header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: blue;
}

#splitter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: violet;
}

#right-header {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

#data {
  background: red;
}

#graph {
  background: yellow;
}

#splitter {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: pink;

}

#right-content {
  background: lime;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

#left-content {
  background: gold;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

#footer {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
<html>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="main-header">Header</div>
    <div id="categoryViewContainer">
      <div id="data">

        <div id="header">
          <div id="left-header">
            <p>HeaderLeft</p>
          </div>
          <div id="right-header">
            <p>HeaderRight : dsafkljsadklfjkslajdfkljksaldfkasd</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="splitter">
           <div id="left-content">
            <p>LeftContent</p>
            <p>LeftContent</p>
            <p>LeftContent</p>
            <p>LeftContent</p>
            <p>LeftContent</p>
            <p>LeftContent</p>
            <p>LeftContent</p>
            <p>LeftContent</p>
            <p>LeftContent</p>
            <p>LeftContent</p>
            <p>LeftContent</p>
            <p>LeftContent</p>
            <p>LeftContent</p>
            <p>LeftContent</p>
            <p>LeftContent</p>
            <p>LeftContent</p>
            <p>LeftContent</p>
            <p>LeftContent</p>
          </div>
           <div id="right-content">
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>          
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div id="graph">
        <p>GraphGraphGraph</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      Footer
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>




They aren't scrolling because there is nothing to scroll to. Your content has not overflowed off the edge of the frame, therefore no scrolling is required. Just setting that you want to see scrollbars by default doesn't change this. And currently those elements are expanding to fit whatever is inside them. Once you either a) add content to those elements that naturally goes off their edge, or b) limit the height/width of those elements to a smaller size than the existing content - the scrollbars will then do something!

I don't really understand. Just make the window smaller, and it overflows, no? If I add "auto" instead of scroll it adds scrollbars just fine. Just not the way I need it

The height of the children are resized by flex by default, and you are missing a constraint on height and width. Also, your requirement will cause the two horizontal scroll bar to not be showing unless the vertical scroll bar scrolls to the end. Is that what you want?

If I understand your problem correctly... the issue is caused by the align-items property on the #splitter
When using flex, the align-items property is set to stretch by default.
If you change that to flex-start, it no longer stretches (or in this case: no longer shrinks) the 2 inner containers to be the same height.
Try adding these 2 values to your jsfiddle (the max-height just lets us see the effect):
#splitter {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background: violet;
    
    align-items:flex-start; /* added to give scrollbar */
    max-height:20em;        /* added for visibility in your example */

    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: pink;
}

Source: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#aa-align-items

that actually helped, thanks! I had to add an overflow hidden on thecategoryViewContainer, a display flex on data, and your align-items on the splitter and header. Now it works although I don't really understand why. I added the solution fiddle as an answer.

I got it working like I wanted, but I don't really understand why it works.
Why do I have to add flex on the wrapper div? Why do I have to add an "align-items: start"? Why the Overflow Hidden on the "data" and "categoryViewCointainer" div?
https://jsfiddle.net/MBittel/hf425rvj/3/


html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
  
div {
  margin: 5px;
}

p {
  margin: 5px;
  background: green;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

#main-header,
#footer {
  background: silver;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#categoryViewContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
  background: orange;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: blue;

  align-items:start;
}

#right-header {
  overflow-x: auto;
  
}

#data {
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#row1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color:white;
  height:90px;
}

#row2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:black;
}


#graph {
  width: 300px;
  background: yellow;
}

#splitter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: violet;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  align-items:start;
}

#right-content {
  background: lime;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#left-content {
  background: gold;
}

#footer {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
<html>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="main-header">Header</div>
    <div id="categoryViewContainer">
      <div id="data">

       <div id="header">
          <div id="left-header">
            <p>Liquidity Left</p>
          </div>
          <div id="right-header">
            <p>Liquidity Right : dsafkljsadklfjkslajdfkljksaldfkasd</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      
       <div id="splitter">
           <div id="left-content">
            <p>Left</p>
            <p>Left</p>
            <p>Left</p>
            <p>Left</p>
            <p>Left</p>
            <p>Left</p>
            <p>Left</p>
            <p>Left</p>
            <p>Left</p>
            <p>Left</p>
            <p>Left</p>
            <p>Left</p>
            <p>Left</p>
            <p>Left</p>
            <p>Left</p>
            <p>Left</p>
            <p>Left</p>
            <p>Left</p>
          </div>
           <div id="right-content">
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdf</p>
            <p>salkhfjlkösadjkflajsklödfjklösdklfjslködafsdF</p>          
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="graph">
        <p>Graph</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      Footer
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>



